# height change of ExpandableListView not working sometimes at android 4.1

Tags: header, height, expandablelistview

I add a `TextView` as header to `ExpandableListView` and change `TextView` height in a animation. But sometimes height is not changed in UI after i call  `TextView.setHeight`.
I also tried use `LayoutParams.Height` instead `TextView.setHeight`, this issue still exists.

Add Header

```
this.header = new TextView(this.getContext());
    this.addHeaderView(header);


int newHeight = (int) (fromHeight - (fromHeight - toHeight) * interpolatedTime);

            header.setHeight(newHeight);
```

After setHeight is called, UI doesn't change sometimes. But if i measure header's height , its value is correct.